# Вывести файлы директории, сортированные по дате модификации

Tags: linux, консоль, rhel

Какую команду в консоли нужно использовать для вывода файлов директории, сортированных по дате модификации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у программы *ls* есть опция `-t`, при указании которой выводимый ею список файлов/каталогов будет отсортирован по дате модификации (сначала — более новые):

```
$ ls -t каталог
```

а с помощью опции `-r` можно поменять порядок сортировки на противоположный:

```
$ ls -t -r каталог
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!